# How to get bounds of OrthographicView with deck.gl

Tags: deck.gl

I'd like to make a minimap of `OrthographicView` and draw the bounds path.

I can get the `viewState` which has its `width`, `height`, `target`, and `zoom`.
But how can I get or compute the `bounds` (top, right, bottom, left coordinates of current view)?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a `viewState`, you can get the bounds with the following code:

```js
const viewportBounds = () => {
    const { width, height } = viewState.main;
    if (!width) return null;
    const view = new OrthographicView(viewState.main);
    const viewport = view._getViewport();

    const topLeft = viewport.unproject([0, 0]);
    const topRight = viewport.unproject([width, 0]);
    const bottomLeft = viewport.unproject([0, height]);
    const bottomRight = viewport.unproject([width, height]);

    return [[topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, topLeft]];
}
```